# how to get activeMQ queue name from command line?

Tags: activemq-classic

I need to run a test on a remote host that has activeMQ running on it and I want to verify if the name of the queue is the right name by comparing it with a local file. I used bstat to get the status of activeMQ and then greped the part that has destionName but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it through command line or shell not java?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

You could use the command line tool "[a](https://github.com/fmtn/a/)".

`a -b tcp://remote-broker-hostname:61616 --list-queues`

would print

```
Queues:
Queue4
DELAYED
ChatMessages
Operation completed in 22ms (excluding connect)
```

It's written in java.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of that tool.

Answer (score 5):

Try **activemq query** command work with -QQueue and -view arguments.

```
#apache-activemq-5.10/bin/activemq query  -QQueue=* --view Name | grep Name

Name = test.queue
Name = notification-q
```

And you can pass the argument "--jmxurl" with proper value to communicate to remote ActiveMQ Server.

Answer (score 0):

I use this tool [jmxterm](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/jmxterm+quickstart) to get ActiveMQ queue statistics & verify queue consumers from a bash script.

The following commands connects to AMQ ruuning on localhost to get few statistics of a Queue 'MyQueue'

```
open service:jmx:rmi://localhost:44444/jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/karaf-root -u user -p password
get -s -d org.apache.activemq -b BrokerName=default,Destination=MyQueue,Type=Queue QueueSize EnqueueCount DequeueCount ConsumerCount
```